# Debian Jessie Qemu KVM GPU Passthrough to Windows Virtual Machine guest Virt-Manager error Bus PCI not found

Tags: debian, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu

I'm having problems with Virt-Manager not wanting to boot a VM and giving error:

```
Error starting domain: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: char device redirected to /dev/pts/3 (label charserial0)
qemu-system-x86_64: -device ioh3420,bus=pci,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1: Bus 'pci' not found
```

If I click Details here's the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 96, in cb_wrapper
callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 117, in tmpcb
callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/domain.py", line 1160, in startup
self._backend.create()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 917, in create
if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: char device redirected to /dev/pts/3 (label charserial0)
```

qemu-system-x86_64: -device  ioh3420,bus=pci,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1: Bus 'pci' not found

I manually added some commandline things with virsh edit to the xml config for the VM because virt-manager didn't have those options ie for GPU BIOS file etc. Here are the qemu commandline tags:

```
<qemu:commandline>
<qemu:arg value='-device'/>
<qemu:arg value='ioh3420,bus=pci,addr=1c.0,multifunction=on,port=1,chassis=1,id=root.1'/>
<qemu:arg value='-device'/>
<qemu:arg value='vfio-pci,host=04:00.0,bus=root.1,addr=00.0,multifunction=on,x-vga=on,romfile=/home/me/Downloads/Sapphire.R9280X.3072.131127_2.rom'/>
<qemu:arg value='-device'/>
<qemu:arg value='vfio-pci,host=04:00.1,bus=root.1'/>
<qemu:arg value='-bios'/>
<qemu:arg value='/usr/share/seabios/bios.bin'/>
<qemu:arg value='-cpu'/>
<qemu:arg value='host,kvm=off'/>
</qemu:commandline>
```

uname -a

```
Linux vmserver 3.16.0-customvmkernel #1 SMP Sun Sep 28 00:34:42 PDT 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

kvm --version

```
QEMU emulator version 2.1.0 (Debian 2.1+dfsg-4), Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed bus=pcie.0 or bus=pci to bus=pci.0  apparently the way its names depends on architecture used in xml file. Mine used 
instead of the more popular machine q35 definitions which would default to pcie.0

It boots without that error now.

Comment: If this is resolved, please mark it as such by ticking the check mark. It still shows up as an unanswered question.

Comment: Yes, I had a very similar issue when using q35 for the first time, as it's much more strict about the virtual architecture.